# How do I specify a variable Excel range?

Tags: excel, worksheet-function, excel-2011

I'd like to be able to dynamically specify a range in Excel, based on row/column variables.

Let's say I have a file with contents that look sort of like this:

```
   A   B   C   D   E
1  10  11  12  13  14
2  51  52  53  54  55
```

If I wanted to sum the items in row 1, columns 2-4 (i.e. 11 + 12 + 13), how would I specify that?

If I were doing it by hand, I'd type:

```
=SUM(B1:D1)
```

...but how do I programatically generate that range definition on the fly, knowing only the wanted row (1) and column numbers (2-4)?

```
=SUM(????)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

(I'm using Microsoft Excel 2011 for Mac, so Excel VBA/macro-based solutions won't work for me.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I had the same need--looks like the `OFFSET` function will let you do that.

So for the above:

```
=SUM(OFFSET(A1,0,1,1,3))
```

to break it down:

```
OFFSET(reference cell,
       row offset from ref cell to start the range,
       col offset to start the range, height of range you want,
       width of range you want)
```

you can make the offsets zero if you want, or `+` to ref down, `-` to ref up

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how the "known" row and column numbers are referenced
For example if they are values in cells on the sheet:

```
     A          B
 9   Row        1
10   ColStart   1
11   ColEnd     4
```

Use a the `INDRECT` function to build a range reference

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("R"&B9&"C"&B10&":R"&B9&"C"&B11,FALSE))
```

Comment: `INDIRECT` must be avoided whenever possible. It is volatile, that is, recalculates each time any cell changes.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you want.
Did you mean this?

```vb
dim parent_range as range
dim child_range as range

set parent_range = me.range("a1:e2")
set child_range = range(parent_range.rows(1).cells(2), parent_range.rows(1).cells(4))

msgbox "=sum(" & child_range.address(false, false, xla1) & ")"
```

Or did you want it as a formula?

```
=SUM(INDEX($A$1:$E$2,1,2):INDEX($A$1:$E$2,1,4))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, GSerg. Unfortunately, I'm using Microsoft Excel 2011 for Mac, which doesn't support Excel VBA macros. I guess I'm looking for a pure-Excel solution.

Comment: @Anirvan Try the formula then.

Comment: That's strange I've developed macros for Excel 2011 for Mac there are a few quirks compared to Windows but for the most part everything was the same. I would be surprised if you can't use this in Excel 2011 for mac.